# not work $_GET['id'] in a anchore tab

Tags: javascript, php, css

i want to do bellow but not get the id value on that tab.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo 'name.php?id='.$row->id.'&'.'#editModal';?>">
Edit</a>
```

After click the tab open but the id field show null.
Any one can help me to find out the solution.

Codes that mention in comments

```
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo 'name.php?id='.$row->id.'&'.'#editModal';?>">Edit</a> 
<br>
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="editModal" class="modal fade"> 
<?php

 $auto_id = $_GET['id']; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id = '" .$auto_id. "'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0){ $row = mysql_fetch_object($result); $tbl_name = $row->tbl_name;}
?> 

<label>Name</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="tbl_name" value="<?php echo $tbl_name;?>" placeholder="Name">
```

Comment: full link ...............<a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo '../modules/inventory/bank-name.php?bkid='.$row->id.'&'.'#editModal';?>">Edit</a>

Comment: Post the code where you set the field value. Also, check the html that gets generated.

Comment: This happens because `$row->id` doesn't hold the value you expect.  Go back and study how this variable gets its value. That's where your problem probably is.

Comment: It would be nice to post your full code just like FirstOne said or you go back and recheck the value of `$row->id` just as BettleJuice said. Probably its not passing the required value

Comment: no it;s not like that...because if i send bellow link the value found .... <a href="<?php echo 'name.php?id='.$row->id;?>">Edit</a‌​> ............ but when i send the link like .......... <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo 'name.php?id='.$row->id.'&'.'#editModal';?>">Edit</a‌​> ....the value not pursed ..... i think the issue on #anchore where the value not able to send ....

Comment: Tell us how you want the rendered link to look like

Comment: <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo 'name.php?id='.$row->id.'&'.'#editModal';?>">Edit</a> <br> <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="editModal" class="modal fade"> <?php $auto_id = $_GET['id']; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id = '" .$auto_id. "'"); if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0){ $row = mysql_fetch_object($result); $tbl_name = $row->tbl_name;}?> <label>Name</label><br><input type="text" name="tbl_name" value="<?php echo $tbl_name;?>" placeholder="Name">

Comment: @azad PLZ add you code to question body and comment more info on it to other can help you

Answer (score 0):

till no solution....

id.'&'.'#editModal';?>">Edit 
   0){ $row = mysql_fetch_object($result); $tbl_name = $row->tbl_name;}?> Name
" placeholder="Name">